# Importing less.js to laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, less

I'm having a hard time getting my project to detect my `less.js` folder.

I'm using laravel 5.1, and I'm not sure where to put my `less.js` folder - since for Bootstrap and jQuery I just imported the src from a URL.

I currently have my `less.js` folder I downloaded under:

> resources > assets > less > *less.js folder I downloaded*

I currently have my `styles.less` in my views while I try to figure this out.

My `app.php` head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could quickly let me know where to drop the folder!

Thanks!

*edit*:

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGo1B.jpg

*edit2*:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkXeJ.jpg

The error in question:

Status 500 Type Script,

> http://localhost:8000/reviewcourse/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only assets published at `public/` folder are available. So, you need to drop files there:

```
public/assets/less/download_folder/less.js
```

Then load it with:

```
<script src="{!! url('assets/less/download_folder/less.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Another way/solution is to publish assets from `/resources` to `public/` via [Elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir#copying-files-and-directories):

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    // location, origin
    mix.copy('assets/less/download_folder/less.js', 'resources/assets/less/folder/less.js');
});
```

### EDIT

I will assume that `less.js` is inside of `public/assets/less/lessjs/dist/less.js`. Then, load it as:

```
<script src="{!! url('assets/less/lessjs/dist/less.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Well, you need to understand that files under `resources/` will never be available for browser. Your files must stay in `public/` folder

Comment: Changing that right now, sorry I am *really* new to laravel!

Comment: Drop files into `resources/` is ok only if you will manage assets via `Elixir`, because of it uses a NodeJS's module named Gulp. If you are not confident with Elixir, then drop the files directly in `public/` without problems :)

Comment: Still having some trouble, receiving 404 not found, is it a problem that I do not see a less.js file in the folder I downloaded?

Comment: update the post showing the files moved to `public/`, then we could see the new path.

Comment: The 404 error was due to a typo, eek, back to the error from the screenshot now

Comment: Progress made! getting very close, it can't find my styles.less folder, I am calling it the same as in the screenshots in my header, it's located in my resources > views at the moment beside my app.blade.php. I think it's safe to assume this is the wrong place, where should I move it?

Comment: I tried moving it to a folder css under public, and larevel auto-href'd it for me, but I am still receiving 404 not found, just for my .less now

Comment: Every file just need to stay under public. `.less` file too, and load it as the same way of another ones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96752/discussion-between-arthur-and-manix).

Answer (score 1):

use this script at your html head

```
<script src="{!! asset('less/less.js') !!}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Received this error: "GET http://localhost:8000/reviewcourse/%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset="

Comment: sorry my typo, i've edited my answer, it's not assets but asset